# Java: only first word of string being output?

Tags: java, string

I've used the Scanner var = input.nextLine(); 
It works for my name variable but not address?
Here is my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("What is your name?");
String name = input.nextLine();

System.out.println("How old are you?");
int age = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Where do you live?");
String address = input.nextLine();

System.out.println("Your name is " + name + ".\n You are " + age + " years old." + "\n You live at " + address + ".");
```

And here's what it's displaying:

```
What is your name?
Yassine assim
How old are you?
17
Where do you live?
Your name is Yassine assim.
 You are 17 years old.
 You live at .
```

Comment: it is answered completely at: <br/>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo
<br/>
Duplicate question !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int age = input.nextInt();` consumes the `int` you typed but that's it, you surely return to line after if BUT this char (return line) has not been consumed

And so `input.nextLine();` of adress will do it directly

---

*2 options :*

1. `int age = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());` take all line and convert to `int`
2. `int age = input.nextInt();   input.nextLine();` take int and use, then consume return like